# Elasticsearch- Nested Aggregations D3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to create D3 charts based on elasticsearch nested aggregation. While I can plot a chart based on the first aggregation, I am not sure why I cant plot a similar chart on the nested a subsequent aggregation. Can anyone suggest what I should do?

My code:

```
            esClient.search({

                    index: 'vehicle',

                    body: {
                        query:{


                            match:{

                                _all:searchTerms

                            }
                        },




                                    aggs: {
                                        touchdowns: {
                            terms: {    
                                 field: "country",
                                    size:5
                                  },

                                    aggs: {
                                        corp: {
                                                 terms: {    
                                                 field: "companyName",
                                                    size:5

                                                 }
                                                 }
                                                 },


                                                     }
                                                },   

                        sort: [sortObject],
                        from: resultsPage * 10,

                    }




            }).then(function(es_return){
                deferred.resolve(es_return);
```

//// Pie Chart first aggregation

```
var touchdowns = es_return.aggregations.touchdowns.buckets;
    // d3 donut chart
    var width = 600,
        height = 300,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
    var color = ['#ff7f0e', '#d62728', '#2ca02c', '#1f77b4'];
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 60)
        .innerRadius(120);
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function (d) { return d.doc_count; });
    var svg = d3.select("#donut-chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/1.4 + "," + height/2 + ")");
    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(touchdowns))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");
    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function (d, i) { return color[i]; });
    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.key; });
```

//// Pie Chart

```
var touchdowns = es_return.aggregations.touchdowns.buckets.corp.buckets;
    // d3 donut chart
    var width = 600,
        height = 300,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
    var color = ['#ff7f0e', '#d62728', '#2ca02c', '#1f77b4'];
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 60)
        .innerRadius(120);
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function (d) { return d.doc_count; });
    var svg = d3.select("#donut-chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/1.4 + "," + height/2 + ")");
    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(touchdowns))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");
    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function (d, i) { return color[i]; });
    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .text(function (d) { return d.assignee.key; });

    }, function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        return deferred.promise;};
```

Comment: Does the program crash or display incorrectly?

Comment: It doesn't crash as I can get the first pie chart on my html page. But I also wanted the second map to be plotted, but for that I can see an error in the console saying: angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property 'buckets' of undefined
    at pie.js:221
    at processQueue (angular.js:15757)
    at angular.js:15773
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17025)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16841)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17133)
    at done (angular.js:11454)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11652)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11593) . Is this d problem?

Comment: I suspect the problem could be here: var touchdowns = es_return.aggregations.touchdowns.buckets.corp.buckets;

Comment: You may want to talk to http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~larsko/ He is on SO and one of the best at analyzing code, particularly D3 and its subsets. You may want to send him a quick message to check out this quesiton.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff

Comment: Thanks.. I just sent him a message.

Comment: No I unfortunately didn't ..